# How do I detect if the mouse is hovering over a button? PyGame button class is not displaying the text or changing colour on hover

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, pygame

I have created a button class in pygame and although the button itself is displaying, my text is not showing up. Also I have some conditions to change the colour when the mouse is over the button. I have achieved the desired result using hard coded values in my main function, however I want to use a class the handle my various button as I might have quite a few buttons.

---

### Given below are some classes that I'm using

---

**Fonts**

```
class Fonts:
    def __init__(self, font, antialias, text, color, x, y):
        self.font = font
        self.antialias = antialias
        self.text = text
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def draw(self, win):
        win.blit(self.font.render(self.text, self.antialias, (self.color)), (self.x, self.y))
```

**Button**

```
class Button:
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, text, fontsize):
        self.color = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.text = text
        self.fontsize = fontsize
        self.courier_button_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Courier", self.fontsize)

    def draw(self, pos):
        x, y = pos
        text_width, text_height = self.courier_button_font.size(self.text)
        if self.x < x < self.width and self.y < y < self.height:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (211, 211, 211), (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
            buttontext = Fonts(courier_font, True, f"{self.text}", BLACK,
                               int(self.width / 2 - text_width / 2), int(self.height / 2 - text_height / 2))
            buttontext.draw(screen)


        else:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
            buttontext = Fonts(courier_font, True, f"{self.text}", BLACK,
                               (self.width / 2 - text_width / 2), (self.height / 2 - text_height / 2))
            buttontext.draw(screen)

    def isOver(self, pos):
        x, y = pos
        if self.x < x < self.width and self.y < y < self.height:
            return True
        else:
            pass
```

---

### The functions where I'm using my button

```
FireTowerButton = Button(BLACK, 810, 200, 80, 30, "Fire Tower", 20)

def ShowTowers(mouse):
    mousex, mousey = mouse
    screen.fill((147, 207, 14))
    FireTowerButton.draw(mouse)

def main():
    run = True
    screen.fill(BLACK)
    # screen.blit(enemy1, (90, 90))
    while run:
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        ShowTowers(mouse)
        screen.blit(money_image, (790, 0))
        screen.blit(background_image, (0, 0))
        enemy1_spawn(wave_number)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (770, 75, 30, 90))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()

        clock.tick(FPS)
        pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition

> ```py
> if self.x < x < self.width and self.y < y < self.height:
> ```

is wrong. You have to evaluate if `x < self.x + self.width` and `y < self.y + self.height`:

```py
if self.x < x < self.x + self.width and self.y < y < self.y + self.height:
    # [...]
```

Anyway, I recommend to [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) / [`collidepoint()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidepoint) for the collision test:

```py
button_rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
if button_rect.collidepoint((x, y):
    # [...]
```

`button_rect` can be used further for drawing the rectangle:

```py
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (211, 211, 211), button_rect)
```

The code can be simplified a lot by the use of an attribute `rect` rather than the separate attributes `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`:

```py
class Button:
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, text, fontsize):
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)
        self.text = text
        self.fontsize = fontsize
        self.courier_button_font = pygame.font.SysFont("Courier", self.fontsize)

    def draw(self, pos):

        button_color = (211, 211, 211) if self.rect.collidepoint(pos) else self.color
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, button_color, self.rect)

        text_width, text_height = self.courier_button_font.size(self.text)
        textpos = (self.rect.centerx - text_width // 2, self.rect.centery - text_height // 2)
        buttontext = Fonts(courier_font, True, self.text, BLACK, textpos)
        buttontext.draw(screen)

    def isOver(self, pos):
        return self.rect.collidepoint(pos)
```

Comment: Thank you, just make sure to remove the colon in the last line of your code.