# Pygame TikTacToe Player Winning Problem How To Fix?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a tiktactoe and I have a problem with my player winning like the game even tho I dont get 3 in a row and I just get [VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/7561d8aa4e177045aed9c70559dd56d4) << I didnt event get 3 in a row it just won the game for player 2

my buttons position

```
                   
white = (250,250,250)
greenbutton2 = button((0,255,0),190,215,100,100, '2')

greenbutton3 = button((0,255,0),335,215,100,100, '3')

greenbutton4 = button((0,255,0),71,215,100,100, '4')

greenbutton5 = button((0,255,0),71,350,100,100, '5')

greenbutton6 = button((0,255,0),190,350,100,100, '6')

greenbutton7 = button((0,255,0),335,350,100,100, '7')


greenbutton8 = button((0,255,0),70,90,100,100, '8')

greenbutton9 = button((0,255,0),190,90,100,100, '9')

greenbutton10 = button((0,255,0),335,90,100,100, '10')

greenbutton4 = button((0,255,0),71,215,100,100, '4')
```

what I did for example for the first one is ***215,215,215*** if my partics are over those it should blit the winning image but it blits another image [IMAGE](https://gyazo.com/19662d80f621ac7bbc9eef41790c14df) but its not blitting the correct image instead its blitting this  [VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/3ca4a4e46f03c038e90fad17d92da91b) << its the same for all of them it keeps blitting the wrong images and sometimes even though I dont get 3 in a row for the X player or the O enemy  it will say I win is there a way I could fix this?

this is for my X player

```
    # player 2 winning for the rows part
    count = sum([1 if partic.y in [215, 215, 215] else 0 for partic in partics])
    if count == 3:
        lines.append(line(0,0,0,0,white))



    count = sum([1 if partic.y in [90, 90, 90] else 0 for partic in partics])
    if count == 3:
        lines.append(lin(0,0,0,0,white))
   

    count = sum([1 if partic.y in [350, 350, 350] else 0 for partic in partics])
    if count == 3:
        lines.append(liner(0,0,0,0,white))



    count = sum([1 if partic.x in [335, 335, 335] else 0 for partic in partics])
    if count == 3:
        lines.append(low(0,0,0,0,white))


    count = sum([1 if partic.x in [190, 190, 190] else 0 for partic in partics])
    if count == 3:
        lines.append(lowe(0,0,0,0,white))


    count = sum([1 if partic.x in [71, 71, 70] else 0 for partic in partics])
    if count == 3:
        lines.append(lower(0,0,0,0,white))


    count = sum([1 if partic.y in [90, 215, 350] else 0 for partic in partics])
    if count == 3:
        lines.append(win(0,0,0,0,white))

    count = sum([1 if partic.x in [335, 71, 190] else 0 for partic in partics])
    if count == 3:
        lines.append(winner(0,0,0,0,white))
```

and this is for my O player

```
    # player 1 winning for the rows part
    count = sum([1 if parti.y in [215, 215, 215] else 0 for parti in parts])
    if count == 3:
        lines.append(line(0,0,0,0,white))



    count = sum([1 if parti.y in [90, 90, 90] else 0 for parti in parts])
    if count == 3:
        lines.append(lin(0,0,0,0,white))
   

    count = sum([1 if parti.y in [350, 350, 350] else 0 for parti in parts])
    if count == 3:
        lines.append(liner(0,0,0,0,white))



    count = sum([1 if parti.x in [335, 335, 335] else 0 for parti in parts])
    if count == 3:
        lines.append(low(0,0,0,0,white))


    count = sum([1 if parti.x in [190, 190, 190] else 0 for parti in parts])
    if count == 3:
        lines.append(lowe(0,0,0,0,white))


    count = sum([1 if parti.x in [71, 71, 70] else 0 for parti in parts])
    if count == 3:
        lines.append(lower(0,0,0,0,white))


    count = sum([1 if parti.y in [90, 215, 350] else 0 for parti in parts])
    if count == 3:
        lines.append(win(0,0,0,0,white))

    count = sum([1 if parti.x in [335, 71, 190] else 0 for parti in parts])
    if count == 3:
        lines.append(winner(0,0,0,0,white))
```

my full code
[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/HHTft4d9)

Comment: Sorry, but I think you got something fundamentally wrong. A condition like `partic.y in [215, 215, 215] `  makes no sense. Either `partic.y` is 215 or it is not. It is the same as `partic.y == 215`.

Comment: I recommend investigating the answer to your one of your previous questions: [Pygame Tic Tak Toe Logic? How Would I Do It](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64825967/pygame-tic-tak-toe-logic-how-would-i-do-it)

Comment: What's the different between `parts` and `partics`?  Can you please explain why the  algorithm is checking the `score` in the `turns()` function.  I don't understand it.

Comment: its checking if my score is 2 and I am hover any of my buttons then Player X should go and if my score is 3 and my O is over any button then player 2 Should go  I got everything working expect the part to check if the player wins or not  the parts list is for player 2 and the partics list is for player 1 I have 2 defferent classes to display different images for X and O thats why I used to defferent list there to

Comment: I see the method you did but I am trying to think of a different way I could do this I tried to check for collisions like `if [partic.rect.colliderect(greenbutton2.rect) and partic.rect.colliderect(greenbutton3.rect) and partic.rect.colliderect(greenbutton4.rect) for partic in partics]:
        lines.append(liner(0,0,0,0,white))` but this method is not working well it only checks if I click either one of them then is clicked then I win

Comment: I am going to add  the sprites that I am using to see what is going on if you like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to simply use the status of a `.result` in your `button()` class.

```
class button():
    def __init__(self, color, x,y,width,height, text=''):
        # ...
        self.result = ''    # empty

    def getResult( self ):
        return self.result

    def setResult( self, value ):
        self.result = value

    def reset( self ):
        self.result = ''   # back to empty state
```

Then when you create a `Parti` or `Partic`, tell the button to remember the result:

```
if score == 2:
    if greenbutton4.isOver(pos):
        greenbutton4.setResult( 'x' )
        partics.append(Partic(71,215,100,100,white))

#  ... 

if score == 3:
    if greenbutton4.isOver(pos):
        greenbutton4.setResult( 'o' )
        parts.append(Parti(71,215,100,100,white))
```

There are only 8 ways to win at tic-tac-toe / noughts-and-crosses:  3x horizontal, 3x vertical, and 2x diagonals.  This is a fairly simple check:

```
def winner( b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b8 ):
    """ Given the buttons 1-9 in order from top-left to bottom right
        return whether 'x' or 'o' has won the game, or None and which
        line/row/vertical the win was made on """
    winner = ( None, None )
    # make a grid of the board-state for iteration
    board = [ [ b1.getResult(), b2.getResult(), b3.getResult() ],
              [ b4.getResult(), b5.getResult(), b6.getResult() ],
              [ b7.getResult(), b8.getResult(), b9.getResult() ] ]

    # EDIT: some debug code
    print( "BOARD IS: ")
    print( " %3s | %3s | %3s " % ( b1.getResult(), b2.getResult(), b3.getResult() ) )
    print( "-----+-----+-----" )
    print( " %3s | %3s | %3s " % ( b4.getResult(), b5.getResult(), b6.getResult() ) )
    print( "-----+-----+-----" )
    print( " %3s | %3s | %3s " % ( b7.getResult(), b8.getResult(), b9.getResult() ) )
    print( "" )


    # check the horizontals
    for row in range( 3 ):
        if ( board[row][0] != '' and
             board[row][0] == board[row][1] and board[row][0] == board[row][2] ):
            winner = ( board[row][0], 'h'+str( row ) )
            break
    # check the verticals
    for col in range( 3 ):
        if ( board[0][col] != '' and
             board[0][col] == board[1][col] and board[0][col] == board[2][col] ):
            winner = ( board[col][0], 'v'+str( col ) )
            break
    # diagonals
    if ( board[1][1] != '' ):
        if ( board[0][0] == board[1][1] and board[2][2] == board[1][1] ):
            winner = ( board[1][1], 'd1' )
        elif ( board[0][2] == board[1][1] and board[2][0] == board[1][1] ):
            winner = ( board[1][1], 'd2' )
    return winner
```

The code seems to create the buttons with `button2` at the centre (based on the video), so the call to this function would be something like:

```
player_wins, row = winner( greenbutton8,  greenbutton9,  greenbutton10,   
                           greenbutton4,  greenbutton2,  greenbutton3,  
                           greenbutton5,  greenbutton6,  greenbutton7 )
if ( player_wins != None ):
    print( "Player "+ player_wins + " has won on " + row )
```

Comment: I am getting this error     `player_wins, row = winner( greenbutton8,  greenbutton9,  greenbutton10,
TypeError: __init__() takes 6 positional arguments but 10 were given`
>>>

Comment: also does the code you provided works for both because when is player X turn its going to be PLayer O turn does it check for player O to?

Comment: Did you paste something incorrectly?  The error refers to `__init__()` not `winner()`.  Something is wrong here.  The function doesn't care who the winner is, it returns which ever symbol fills the cells in the winning pattern.  It could be `o` and `x` (or carrot & banana).

Comment: yes I pasted in correctly but its still giving me the error [image](https://gyazo.com/7b80f92c60c215569b6ddc7df2ed216a)

Comment: Update your pastebin, I'll take a quick look

Comment: You have a class named `winner`, so you'll need to rename the class or the function.

Comment: ok I fixed that but when I do 3 in a row of any of the buttons nothing gettings returned [image](https://gyazo.com/d41ee4987750af9d4efadfbc0f66762f)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224948/discussion-between-kingsley-and-habib-ismail).